# JSON parsing with Play: why is a list being parsed this way?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Here is a JSON list I want to process:

```
scala> jsonStructure \ "response" \ "docs"
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"title":"the very first document"},{"title":"on brick walls"}]
```

I tried converting it to a list, but I got something with different semantics, a list whose only element is that list:

```
scala> jsonStructure \ "response" \\ "docs"
res3: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List([{"title":"the very first document"},{"title":"on brick walls"}])

scala> res3.size
res4: Int = 1
```

I tried this kludge, which does the trick:

```
scala> (jsonStructure \ "response" \ "docs").as[Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]
res9: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List({"title":"the very first document"}, {"title":"on brick walls"})

scala> res9 size
res10: Int = 2
```

---

Why did the `\\` not work? What is the idiomatic way to understand a JsValue into a JsArray? While still maintaining the "navigating using and \ never fails" philosophy? I want to parse deeper structures, like a list of obj inside an obj which was a list element; I want a method that wont become unwieldy for deeply nested structures.

Feel free to correct my approach if you find it complicated, brittle etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted just the list of title entries, you probably would want to write something like:

```
json \\ "title"
```

Which returns:

```
List("the very first document", "on brick walls")
```

The `\\` works by listing any element matching your path selector (at current level and all the descendants). Since there is essentially one `docs` element, it returns a list with one element. Only when you ask for a title, it will return a list of titles.

But from you approach you probably wanted to pattern-match a JsValue on JsArray:

```
  def convert(json : JsValue) : Option[Seq[JsValue]] = json match {
    case JsArray(arr) => Some(arr)
    case _ => None
  }
```

It returns exactly what you wanted:

```
List({"title":"the very first document"}, {"title":"on brick walls"})
```